# Import from Web CSV to the data frame?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, import-from-csv

I've got a CSV file from the link [Hearthstone Arena Card Pickup probability](https://bnetcmsus-a.akamaihd.net/cms/gallery/LN4X4GN4W59R1532566073433.csv)

It's just a list of vectors now, and I want to convert into 9 column data frame. so it may look like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0vrv.png]

My current code is as follows but it's not working at all.

```
hsd <- read.csv("hearthstonedraw.csv", header = TRUE)
hsd1 <- as.data.frame(hsd,ncol = 9)
hsd1
```

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: You shouldn't need to *"convert into 9 column data frame"*. `read.csv` already returns a `data.frame`, so `as.data.frame` is redundant. Are you sure the file is a CSV file?

Comment: read.csv creates a dataframe. Try `str(hsd)` to see this. I confirmed by running `hsd <- read.csv("https://bnetcmsus-a.akamaihd.net/cms/gallery/LN4X4GN4W59R1532566073433.csv", header = TRUE)` and got a datafame...

Answer (score 0):

Answer goest out to Maurits Evers and Adam Sampson.
`read.csv` can read from the address you indicate and automatically converts `character` columns into factors (default behaviour) as well as calulating the number of columns.

```
hsd1 <- read.csv("https://bnetcmsus-a.akamaihd.net/cms/gallery/LN4X4GN4W59R1532566073433.csv", header = TRUE)
str(hsd1)
# 'data.frame': 3931 obs. of  9 variables:
#  $ Draft.Class : Factor w/ 9 levels "Druid","Hunter",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ Card.Name   : Factor w/ 995 levels "Abominable Bowman",..: 716 813 646 500 263 964 549 186 509 984 ...
#  $ Rarity      : Factor w/ 5 levels "basic","common",..: 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 5 2 ...
#  $ Type        : Factor w/ 3 levels "Minion","Spell",..: 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 ...
#  $ Card.Class  : Factor w/ 10 levels "druid","hunter",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ Average     : num  1.47 1.45 1.44 1.17 1.03 ...
#  $ P.1.or.more.: num  0.78 0.776 0.774 0.696 0.649 ...
#  $ P.2.or.more.: num  0.436 0.431 0.428 0.327 0.273 ...
#  $ P.3.or.more.: num  0.1784 0.1757 0.1724 0.1081 0.0819 ...
ncol(hsd1)
# [1] 9
# There are 9 columns in the data frame
```